# Bootstrap nav nav-tab classes not displaying correctly when next to elements that use float left

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I seem to be having an issue using the `.nav` and `.nav-tab` classes when placed next to elements that are using the property `float:left` see the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/imaginatewayne/6eyBh/63/)
It looks to me like it's do with the clearfix in `.nav::after` but when I modify the css to remove `clear:both` the nav-tab gets all messed up.

Basically what I'm trying to do is create two static columns and then a third dynamic column that fills the rest of the page which seemed fine until I started using the tabs where the div containing the tab-content falls below the first and second columns instead of being to the right of them under the tabs where it's meant to be.

Here's the html and css:

html:

```
<div class="col1">
    <section class="s1">
        Section 1
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
    </ul>
</section>
<section class="s2">
    Section 2 
    <ul>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>2</li>
    </ul>
</section>
</div>
<section class="s3">
    Section 3    
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
         <li><a href="#a" data-toggle="tab">a</a></li>
         <li><a href="#b" data-toggle="tab">b</a></li>
         <li><a href="#c" data-toggle="tab">c</a></li>
         <li><a href="#d" data-toggle="tab">d</a></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="a">A</div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="b">B</div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="c">C</div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="d">D</div>
    </div>
</section>
```

css:

```
.s1{
    float:left;
    width: 60px;
    background-color: grey;
}
.s2{
    float:left;
    width: 60px;
    background-color: pink;
}
.s3{
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 100%;
}

.s3 > .tab-content{
        background-color: orange;
}
```

Comment: So what is the problem ? Like what should be the behavior that you are unable to see

Comment: I'll edit the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/imaginatewayne/6eyBh/89/) with the working answer.

The reason it wasn't displaying correctly was because the `clear:both` is in the `.clearfix` mixin which is used in the `.nav` class. This pulls any elements below other elements that are floated left or right.

The fix for this is to modify the `after` where any `.clearfix` has been implemented. In the case of the JSFiddle above I added the following css:

```
.nav::after{
   clear:none;
   height:41px;
}
```

***Additional:*** You will notice that I have had to specify the height of the after now so that it displays correctly. Where this solution falls down is that now anywhere an element uses `clearfix` you will need to manually handle the height.

Answer (score 0):

OK here is the edited answer
Basically you need to make sure that the widths of the divs are properly defined if you are using float;

```
.col1{
    width:100%;
}
.s1{
    float:left;
    width: 10%;
    background-color: grey;
}
.s2{
    float:left;
    width: 10%;
    background-color: pink;
}
.s3{

background-color: yellow;
float:left;
width:80%;    

}
```

here is the updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6eyBh/76/)!

Comment: This just places section 3 below sections 1 and 2. Instead it should be beside them and fill the remaining width of the page.

Comment: I need s1 and s2 to be a static size rather than relative i.e. they need to be in px rather than in % because I don't want them to resize when the size of the browser window is changed, though I do want s3 to resize as the window changes size.

Comment: in that case using JS will solve your problem. get the dynamic width of the col1 and then set width of s3 by subtracting widths of s2 & s3 from s1.